# What does it mean to differentiate a differential quantity with respect to another quantity it is not dependent upon?

Tags: differentiation, integration, calculus

Recently, I came across this equation while solving a few integrations:

*d(xy) = xdy + ydx*

When I searched for its proof, I found that we assume another differential quantity, say *dp*, and then differentiate *d(xy)*, with respect to *p* by applying the product rule and the chain rule. However, I didn't understand the concept of differentiating it with respect to a quantity on which it is independent. What does it signify in physical terms?

Comment: You can think of it like this, the "d" operator maps scalar functions into function which map tiny changes in each variable at a point to change in the scalar function. That is, d( f(x,y) ) = g(x,y,dx,dy)

Comment: "...by applying the product rule and the chain rule" - It seems rather unlikely that a proof of the product rule (your equation) would use the product rule. I suggest to share more details.

Comment: @Filippo I think what is meant is, the "usual" product rule with "usual" dervatives: $$\frac{d}{dx}(fg)=\frac{df}{dx}g+f\frac{dg}{dx}$$ can be used to provide a physicist type proof of this relation, multiplying through by $dx$... ;-)

Comment: @Amit Well, since$$df=\frac{df}{dx}dx$$this is a fully rigorous proof, isn't? :)

Answer (score 2):

Simplest product rule proof is with elementary area increase, which was found by Leibniz :
[image]

$$ d(uv) = A_{tot} - A_{prev} \tag 1$$

Where $A_{tot}$ is current increased area and $A_{prev}$ is previous area without elementary part added. (1) resolves to :

$$ d(uv) = (u+du)(v+dv) - uv \tag 2$$

Expanding multiplication in (2) gives :

$$ d(uv) = vdu + udv + du \cdot dv \tag 3 $$

Since term $du \cdot dv \ll du~(\text{or}~dv)$ it can be omitted from equation (3). Hence we get :

$$ d(uv) = vdu + udv \tag 4 .$$

> However, I didn't understand the concept of differentiating it with respect to a quantity on which it is independent

$$ \frac {\partial f(x)}{\partial y} = 0 $$

because with respect to $y,~~f(x)$ is constant and derivative of constants is always zero.

Answer (score 0):

1. Fix a point $p$ in ${\mathbb R}^n$, or whatever other manifold you're studying functions on.
2. Let $V$ be the vector space of all smooth functions that are defined on some neighborhood of $p$ (that is, $f$ is in $V$ if $f$ is defined on some open set containing $p$).
3. Let $U\subset V$ be the subspace of all functions that vanish at $p$.
4. Let $T\subset U$ be the subspace of all functions that vanish on some neighborhood of $p$.
5. Let $S\subset U$ be the subspace generated by all products $fg$ where $f,g\in U$.
6. Form the quotient $U/(S+T)$ and call this the space of differentials (or cotangent vectors) at $p$.
7. For $f\in V$, note that $f-f(0)$ is in $U$, and hence has an image in $U/(S+T)$.  Call that image $df$.
8. Now that you know what $df$ means, check that the Leibniz rule holds.  This is a good exercise in making sure you've understood the definition.

The business about introducing a third function on which $f$ and $g$ both depend is, I think, very confusing and unnecessary.

Comment: I think the level of the answer is an overkill for the level of the question.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I didn't understand the concept of differentiating it with respect to a quantity on which it is independent. What does it signify in physical terms?

Define $$p(x,y) = x y$$ Now $p(x,y)$, or more simply $p$, depends on both $x$ and $y$ so differentiation can take place as usual.